# sharepoint 2013 designer -programming possibilities and limitations

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

What are the possible functionalities that can be modified or added using sharepoint designer with sharepoint foundation 2013? In terms of programming.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designers main purpose is for creating or modifying Microsoft SharePoint sites, workflows and web pages.

As an example you are able to create and modify workflows but cannot compile any code or build your own custom web parts.

Comment: thanks for the answer.please provide me some useful examples which actually show how things can be coded with sharepoint designer.for example how can a .net module be called from within a sharepoint desine whenever a new list is created in sharepoint.

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is where stackoverflow ends and education begins, we don't provide such things since this is no job. I would advice you to check youtube and whatever educations you can find in your region. Learning SharePoint is hard work.